# Rollback delete of Tridion item

Tags: 2013, cme

I know I can use Version History to rollback a change to a Tridion item.  What if I delete that item and then want to rollback the delete?  Can I do that?  If so how, since the item will be gone from the CME.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid that You can not do this. If you delete any item from Tridion, it is gone forever. The only solution that I can see is that you restore this item from the Previous backups of your Content Manager database. Now if you have changed a lot of data after the delete then an alternate approach that you can follow is as below:

- Take a back up of your existing Content Manager DB
- Restore the older version of Content Manager DB which have the deleted version of the item
- Use Content Porter Tool to create an export package of this deleted Item
- Revert to the latest version of Content Manager DB by restoring the backup of your Latest Content Manager DB
- Again use the Content Porter Tool to import the package you previously created containing the deleted item

Comment: some of the reasoning behind the Delete==Gone decision: you are only able to delete an item which is not (or no longer) in use, so that item has become less important to protect. Another reason is that SDL Tridion is a CMS and not a data warehouse, if all versions of all items (including deleted ones) would be kept, your database would become unmanagebly large.

Comment: You can proactively take Content Porter packages to reduce the database restore parts. In practice, I've moved items to "archive" or dated folders rather than delete them if I might need them later. The input source and rendered content seems to last forever as well (e.g. original request, versions on Dev or Test servers, and archived pages).